# Using OpenCL in the guest system with CPU on Virtual Box, VMWare or Parallels?

Tags: virtualization, opencl

Is it possible to use opencl for the **CPU**, while using some virtualization software (i.e. in the guest system)? I think it becomes more important, while the computation is moving into clouds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, OpenCL for CPU is just another process running in the CPU, with nothing special on it. Virtualization should be possible without problems.

Comment: OK, i have had some problem with the bootcamp partition on my mac. Yesterday i did a clean install of win 7 64 bit SP 1 on VM Ware virtual machine, after that installed intel opencl sdk and everything are running fine. And with 4 cores i can do a skatch for opencl applications, what was the goal (the problem is, that MacOS sucks in support for new development tools).

Comment: I have tried today to use virtual box, but there is a problem with it. OpenCL SDK complains about unknown hardware and cancels the installation.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, it just says that it should be possible without any hints or tips as to how it can be achieved.

Comment: @GilesBathgate The question asks if its possible, not how to achieve it. There are a lot of details missing to answer that. If you don't like the answer, change the question (ask your own).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, Saying it "should be possible" is just speculation though, the question was "is it possible", while he doesn't specifically ask how its possible to achieve, for you to know its possible, it shouldn't be too hard for you to state how. So I've guessed that you don't know how, and you are just assuming that it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Some drivers, like Intel's CPU driver actually does not seem to allow to be installed in Parallels virtual machine for some reason.

To get OpenCL support in Windows running parallels I first booted to run Windows natively and installing drivers there. Then I booted back to OSX and Intel's CPU driver was also available in Parallels. Naturally this approach works only for Bootcamp + Parallels setup.

Comment: Yes it did work. Only intel's installer didn't allow to run on Parallels. Maybe nowadays it works? Also it is worth trying to use some other CPU drivers from amd or pocl (portable opencl driver)

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible when a OpenCL driver is available for the host systems GPU. As far as I know it is not possible for the three systems mentioned. I am sure for Virtual Box. The graphics board emulated is not OpenCL compatible and the virtual box GPU drivers do not support OpenCL.

As far as I know this would only be possible if the guest system would see the original GPU board from the host. You have to check this out and to install the needed OpenCL drivers.

Comment: Oh, it was late... I didn't recognize CPU even it was written bold. OpenCL on CPU should be possible. The drivers should not recognize the difference.